# QTP 11 does not recognise silverlight popup element

Tags: silverlight-4.0, qtp

I'm a tester and currently evaluating QTP 11 on my company's Silverlight 4.0 browser application. I have encountered an issue where QTP does not recognize the popup elements within the Silverlight application.

Is this a known issue with QTP and are they looking into a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASked the question here 
http://h30501.www3.hp.com/t5/Quality-Center-Support-Forum/QTP-11-does-not-recognise-silverlight-popup-element/td-p/33157

Comment: This is not an answer, once (if) you get an answer there you should add the answer and a link to it.

Answer (score 1):

try to record the operations in QTP 11 and then the object is identified, but Using Or or Spy it takes object behind it on main page.
Once you record you can use the script with appropriate changes in Silverlite 4 with QTP 11.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight pop up screens are not identified using Object spy. But we can use sendkeys and perform limited validation on the objects in pop up screens.